# nginx to use a second node as a shadow

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Is it possible to configure nginx to route all traffic to the primary node, but duplicate the requests (and ignore the response) to a second node?  This is for testing a performance update to a web server in production with minimal risk.

I found [Shadow Proxy](https://github.com/twilio/shadow) but was concerned about its impact on performance and stability of a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is not a stable and high performance and easy way to do this for production environment.

here are some methods instead:

1. I found some blogs said using nginx-lua can do this.
2. In our environment, we split the traffic and force some certain requests to our sandbox server, and the ratio is under control. If have problems, only a few users will be affected, and, these group of users could be internal users, such as colleagues of your department or entire company.
3. Recover the requests from the access log for those "GET" requests. for POST requets, we usually using auto test cases.